# Firewall Ports for Filesharing With OSX

Tags: networking, firewall, macosx, file-sharing

I tried searching for this but I'm coming up short. Maybe my wording is wrong.

I have my Ubuntu machine showing on my LAN - and I can see it from the Finder Window in OSX - but it won't connect when my firewall on Ubuntu is running. Of course, I want this on and running at all times. What are the ports I need to open up to accept the incoming traffic for file sharing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

5353 UDP - Multicast DNS - (mdns) is the answer here. Opened this port and can successfully connect to my Linux machine from OSX.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason I don't see an option to add a comment on my iPhone using the StackExchange app, so I'll offer an answer that finally worked for me. I gave up on trying to configure Samba, it never worked, ever. What does work is BitTorrent Sync 2.0 and it is fast, it costs money though, I'm fine with that, it is absolutely the easiest and fastest way to share files between OS X and Ubuntu

Comment: I don't think this is what I am looking for, I believe the file sharing options are already there - I forget what It was i installed to allow it to be seen on the network (im not home so cant check) and it works when my firewall is turned off.

Comment: I know my answer doesn't address your problems with your firewall and file sharing, and I do not expect you accept this as an answer. I would have just added a comment about how I share files, I could not see the option to add a comment to your question.